# Is using assign() a good way to initialise my C++ vector of structs?

Tags: c++, stdvector

The struct

```
struct Vanish
{
  int iCount;
  int iRow;
};
```

I defined a `std::vector` of `Vanish` as a member of my class, and want to initialise it in the constructor like this:

```
class BigClass
{
  public:
    BigClass();
  private:
    std::vector<Vanish> tovanish;
};

void BigClass::BigClass()
{
  Vanish empty = {0,0};
  tovanish.assign(MAX_VANISH, empty);
}
```

Is there a better way, or is this considered OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to do that in the constructor's initializer list:

```
BigClass::BigClass()
: tovanish(MAX_VANISH)
{

}
```

That way, you'll avoid possible vector reallocations. Note that you vector's constructor will value-initialize its elements. Value-initialization of the `int` members in `Vanish` just zeroes them.

Note that in C++11, using uniform-initialization you could specify other values easily:

```
BigClass::BigClass()
: tovanish(MAX_VANISH, {42, 24})
{

}
```

Comment: Will the constructor `Vanish(0,0)` get defined by the compiler, or must I define this myself? - I get an error with this saying `no overloaded function takes 2 arguments`.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a better way?

Yes, sure,

```
BigClass::BigClass() : tovanish(MAX_VANISH) {}
```

This gives you a vector with `MAX_VANISH` value-initialized `Vanish` elements.

Comment: Does that mean that the compiler would do it's thing if I just left the initialisation of `tovanish` out of my default constructor?

Comment: But it initializes the vector with initialized `Vanish` objects, which have two **uninitialized** `int` members. So we also need a proper `Vanish` default c'tor.

Comment: @juanchopanza The vector will default-construct its elements. Default-constructor of `Vanish` is noop, since it only contains `int`s...

Comment: @leemes: Vector uses value-initialization which will initialize POD structures like `Vanish`. No need for any explicit constructor in this case.

Comment: @BeeBand see my edit. This way, you get a vector with `MAX_VANISH` value-initialized `Vanish` elements.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Since C++11 only, according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (c'tor (3)). In C++03 there is a  constructor (2) with `(size_type count, const T& value = T())`, so it's default c'ted. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @leemes: Nah, POD types get default initialized if `()` is omitted, otherwise they get value-initialized. This is valid for C++03 as well.

Comment: @leemes it is hte difference between `Vanish v;` and `Vanish v = Vanish();`. The former is default initialization, the latter is value initialization. Value initialization is performed (indirectly) in C++03 as well as C++11.

Comment: Oh my god, how could I forget. I'm sorry to bother you guys.. Thanks ;)