# Good way to initialise a vector of vectors of struct (each with an initial value)?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I refer to a question I asked earlier, where I was asking the best way to initialise a vector of `struct Vanish` with empty values:

[Is using assign() a good way to initialise my C++ vector of structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003126/is-using-assign-a-good-way-to-initialise-my-c-vector-of-structs)

I accepted the answer:

```
BigClass::BigClass()
: tovanish(MAX_VANISH)
{

}
```

My question now, is what if I want to initialise a vector of vectors of `struct Vanish`, as a member of my class (`BigClass`), but this time initialise each `Vanish` with the value {3,3}. I have:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vanish>> vanish_vectors;
```

In my constructor I tried:

```
BigClass::BigClass():
    vanish_vectors(NUM_COLUMNS, (NUM_ROWS, (3,3)))
  {

  }
```

with the intention of creating NUM_COLUMNS vectors, and in each vector would be NUM_ROWS of struct `Vanish` initialised to the value {3, 3}.

With the debugger I found that this did indeed create NUM_COLUMNS vectors.
However, each of those vectors contained 3 `Vanish` structs, all zero'd out.

What's the best way to initialise those `Vanish` structs with values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is a syntax I'm unfamiliar with, what you tried is actually using the comma *operator*, so `(NUM_COLUMNS, (NUM_ROWS, (3,3)))` becomes `(NUM_COLUMNS,3)`, which passes 3 as the value to construct the vectors from (which will in turn call the vector's constructor with an int, giving you vectors of 3 default-initialised elements)

I think what you need to do is this:

```
// C++11
vanish_vectors(NUM_COLUMNS, std::vector<Vanish>(NUM_ROWS, {3,3}))

// or for older C++ (you will also need to give Vanish a constructor)
vanish_vectors(NUM_COLUMNS, std::vector<Vanish>(NUM_ROWS, Vanish(3, 3)))

// or (as noted in the comments) to keep Vanish as POD in pre-C++11:
vanish_vectors(NUM_COLUMNS, std::vector<Vanish>(NUM_ROWS, makeVanish(3, 3)))
// with a function like this:
Vanish makeVanish( int a, int b ) {
    Vanish thing;
    thing.a = a;
    thing.b = b;
    return thing;
}
```

Which sends a vector to initialise the values with, and that vector contains a struct with values 3, 3 to initialise *its* values.

Comment: My compiler won't accept the curly braces around `3,3`. "Error expected an expression".

Comment: That probably means you're using a pre-C++11 compiler, or you haven't enabled C++11 extensions. You should give your struct a constructor and call that. I'll add a note in the answer.

Comment: @BeeBand alternatively, write a `Vanish makeVanish(int, int);` function which constructs the object for you. That is, if you want your struct to be a POD. Otherwise use the constructor.

Comment: @juan Ok and would it look like: `Vanish* v = new Vanish; v->firstfield = val; v->secondfield = val; return v;` ?

Comment: @juan ok that worked instead of the constructor. yes i wanted it to be a POD.

Comment: @BeeBand noooo! No pointers, no `new`. Just `vanish_vectors(NUM_COLUMNS, std::vector<Vanish>(NUM_ROWS, makeVanish(3, 3)));

Comment: @juan, yes that's what my initialiser looks like for `vanish_vectors` ... but I was describing what `makeVanish()` would look like inside

Comment: @BeeBand simpler: Vanish makeVanish(int a, int b) { return Vanish{a,b};}